# Only start web profiler on matching IPs

Tags: php, silex

Using Silex, how do I limit the web profiler to only start/show for matching IPs?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can do something like:

```
...
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$ips = array('IP1', 'IP2', 'IP3');  //IP's for which to enable web profiler
if (in_array($request->getClientIp(), $ips)) {
    $app->register(new Provider\WebProfilerServiceProvider(), array(
        'profiler.cache_dir' => __DIR__.'/../cache/profiler/',
        'profiler.mount_prefix' => '/_profiler', // this is the default
    ));
}
...
$app->run($request);
```

Comment: I already tried that.

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Accessed request service outside of request scope. Try moving that call to a before handler or controller.'`

Comment: so where do you register the WebProfilerServiceProvider? Inside a Controller? I added this to the entry Point of my application and it works (my index.php file that starts it all). Also ensure that you have the latest versions of all dependencies installed.

Comment: I have a file called "Services.php" which is included directly from index.php which is the entry point of my application. Composer.json - "silex/web-profiler": "~1.0". Using the latest profiler.

Moving it to a controller doesn't make sense. I want to bootstrap it as early as possible. Not sure what before handler I'd use, but that seems odd too.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use

```
$request->getClientIp()
```

as the $app is not really initialized at that point

Instead, use a before handler :

```
$app->before(function (Request $request) use ($app) {
  $ips = array('IP1', 'IP2', 'IP3');  //IP's for which to enable web profiler
  if (in_array($request->getClientIp(), $ips)) {
     //register blah 
  }
});

$app->run();
```

It will be called in `->run()` where context is all set up and everything should be fine.

Comment: I don't get a error, but that doesn't work. I tried using after() and I tried adding `Appliction::EARLY_EVENT`. Neither of which work.

Comment: It must be in the `before()`, in the `after` it will be too late.  
Do you have any notice ?  
What is the value of `$request->getClientIp()` ? (`var_dump` it inside the before closure)

Comment: The condition returns true. Even if I remove the condition, it doesn't work. No notices, nothing is logged.